# Is there a way to numerically count the number of calendar events on a day?

Tags: calendar, applescript

```
set every_Calendar to every calendar

        --set calendarToday_Events to every event whose start date is greater than or equal to time_Today and start date is less than or equal to time_Tomorrow
        set calendarToday_Events to (count (events of every_Calendar whose start date is greater than or equal to time_Today and start date is less than or equal to time_Tomorrow))
        ----------------------------------

say "There are " & calendarToday_Events & " on current date"
```

I'm trying to make a script that says how many events are during a day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must define start and end date using hours minutes seconds with your date, then script bellow gives you the number of events :

```
tell application "Calendar"
set my_Calendars to every calendar
set Total_Events to 0
repeat with a_calendar in my_Calendars
    tell a_calendar to set my_Events to (every event whose (start date is greater than or equal to Debut) and (start date is less than or equal to Fin))
    set Total_Events to Total_Events + (count of my_Events)
end repeat
display dialog (Total_Events)
end tell
```

If you ask directly every event of every calendar, you will get a list of list.

Comment: I declared a start and end date just didn't show in the code; I'll I've that a go, thanks.